# Int size limit for identity column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to limit the identity column using php or asp so a number should not exceeded to create.lets suppose I want to give user permission that he/she only can add 2 user not more than that,how can I do that ?basically I am creating an application in php where maximum 2 stores can be registered for other client should contact me to create 3 or more.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: You should google it...

Comment: This question is unlikely to help anyone in the future and has not been analysed sufficiently before asked

Comment: I am using mysql right now ....

Comment: why don't you try yourself...

Answer (score 2):

The `int` datatype goes up to `2,147,483,647` so going past 10,000 won't be an issue.

See here for SQL Server: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Or here for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

`int` datatype takes

> Integer (whole number) data from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647).

So 10000 not a probelm

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198%28v=sql.80%29.aspx